# how do i disable users on my website from using the command document.cookie or make it so it does not display other cookies for different users

Tags: javascript, security

How can i disable users from viewing cookie information; When using the command

```
    document.cookie
```

I recently typed this command into the developer console and instead of viewing my cookie information it showed the users cookie and session id of the page i was visiting i was wondering if inserting.

```
    if (!document.cookie) {
        alert('Cookies are disabled.');
    }
```

into my website would work if so where can i place this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client side code, such as Javascript, can *always* be modified by the client. There is no way to restrict users from executing javascript within the context of your site or otherwise preventing them from accessing any data sent to the client.

> make it so it does not display other cookies for different users

There is no way you can prevent users from being able to access *their own* cookies, but unless [something is wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) there should not be a way for users to access other users' cookies.

> I recently typed [the `document.cookie`] command into the developer console and instead of viewing my cookie information it showed the users cookie and session id of the page i was visiting

If you are seeing data for the wrong user on the client side, that means the wrong data is being sent on the server side. You cannot address this with javascript.

Comment: what about the ability to edit a cookie to change session id's like javascript:void(document.cookie="user_patrick_isadmin");

Comment: @PatrickGray You can't prevent users from modifying their own session cookie. You can do additional validation on the server side to ensure that even if a user is able to change their session ID to that of another user, they cannot successfully impersonate that user. For example, if you track a user's IP address you can invalidate their session if requests start coming in from a different IP address. I would refer to security.SE for any questions regarding session hijacking and how to prevent it.

Comment: that seems to be the solution I was looking for thank you =D

Comment: @PatrickGray: Look into an HMAC signing implementation such as [JSON Web Tokens](http://jwt.io/) - this mitigates the threat of users tampering with the cookie values as they do not have the secret key to sign it.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons you should not put anything sensitive into cookies. Javascript runs on the client side, meaning nothing us stopping them from removing any stop gaps you out. Put sensitive data securely in the backend.

Comment: Is there any way to hide the cookie info from showing session id number or any info from other users.

Comment: What exactly are you worried is going to happen if someone knows there own sessionid